# Function getting key from singly linked list and error service

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

I got a Sequence (singly linked list):

```
class Sequence
{
    struct Node {
        Key key;
        Info info;
        Node *next;
    };

Node *head = NULL;
```

and a function for that:

```
template <typename Key, typename Info>
Key Sequence<Key, Info>::getKey(int pos)const
{
    Node *curr = head;
    int i = 1;
    while((curr) && (i < pos))
    {
        i++;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    if(curr)
    {
        return curr->key;
    }
    cout << "no Node with such a key" << endl;
    return NULL;
}
```

It should get a key based on given parameter POS, which is position in the list. When it works perfectly for the range of the list, it doesn't for negative values (it should show some text that this node doesn't exist) and values out of a range (same case as for negatives). 
Where is a mistake?

Comment: If you create this sequence: `[4, 3, 2, 1]`. What, do you think, will `getKey(3)` return?

Comment: Should return '2', as we start numerating from 1

Comment: I recommend executing this function with pen on paper.

Comment: @Marta negative positions do not make any sense for a single-linked list. Was your task to look for the value of the "Info" for a given Key instead of the postition?

Comment: Do you really want to return NULL on not found? What is the range of values of your keys that you will put in your list?

Comment: Note: if you have not figured it out yet for a negative pos you will return the key for the head node if it is not NULL.

Comment: Ok, the best solution was to **return head->key** in the end of the function

Answer (score -1):

Keep track of the size of the list inside the `Sequence` object. That allows you to do the check before anything else:

```
template <typename Key, typename Info>
Key Sequence<Key, Info>::getKey(int pos)const
{
    //Add a size() member function to sequence that returns the size
    // Store the size as a member variable
    if(pos >= size() || pos < 0) {
        cout << "no Node with such a key" << endl;
        return NULL; 
    }
    Node *curr = head;
    int i = 1;
    while((curr) && (i < pos))
    {
        i++;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    if(curr)
    {
        return curr->key;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```